# unable to update gitlab-ce on linux mint 17.3

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8

I have gitlab-ce 8.6.6 on Linux mint 17.3.

Gitlab-ce is now upto 8.11.2. If I do an apt-get install gitlab-ce then it tells me that I am already at the newest version.

When I cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list, it shows

deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/linuxmint/ rosa main

This address is no longer available. Running

curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

overwrites the above repository entry with identical entry and running

sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=8.11.2-ce.1

gives me an error of

E: Version ‘8.11.2-ce.1’ for ‘gitlab-ce’ was not found

Is Linux mint no longer supported? Do I need to upgrade to Linux mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04)?

Comment: Why do you select a specific version if you want to upgrade to latest?

Comment: 8.11.2 is the latest and that command  is what was recommended on the gitlab page.
If I do a normal update or install then I already have the latest version (8.6.6) and if I specify the actual latest (8.11.2) then it is not found which suggests a mint problem (?)

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` should do it

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade gitlab-ce

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
gitlab-ce is already the newest version.

GitLab information
Version: 8.6.6

That made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

And a few weeks after I tried this, it suddenly worked and showed up on update. So I presume that the mint repository went from gitlab 8.6.x to 8.11.x.